# How to capture component related events in Unity3d?

Tags: events, unity-game-engine, components

It's easy to capture **GameObject** related events in Unity3d 4.X, such as initializing, changing active state, destroying, etc. A customized **MonoBehaviour** for debugging attached to the GameObject will fulfill the target. But how to capture the **pre-defined** (I mean, I cannot modify the source to add debugging code) component related events?

1. A pre-defined component is enabled/disabled.
2. A pre-defined component is removed/added.

I really want to find out which scripts modify a pre-defined component(MeshRenderer for instance) of a GameObject.

Comment: Fafase has explained `OnEnable`. Also be sure to read a basic tutorial on using UnityEvent which are very handy.

Comment: I have edit my question again to make it more clear, it's easy for customized  components and hard for predefined ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabled/disabled can be followed with:

```
void OnEnable(){ Debug.Log("Being enabled"); }
void OnDisable(){ Debug.Log("Being disabled"); }
```

Concerning removal, I would guess this is a destruction:

```
void OnDestroy(){  Debug.log("Is destroyed"); }
```

If you plan on moving the component around then it is more about the method that will grab it and move it.

As for which script affects, you could use the event pattern:

```
public EventHandler <EventArg> RaiseEvent;
protected void OnRaiseEvent(EventArg args){
    if(RaiseEvent != null{ RaiseEvent(this, args); }
}
```

the other script is listening with:

```
void Start(){
       controller.RaiseEvent += HandleEvent;
   }
   void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArg args){
       MonoBehaviour mb = sender as MonoBehaviour;
       if(mb != null) { Debug.Log("Was modified by " + mb.name); }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks fafase, it works for customized component, but not work for pre-defined components such as MeshRenderer, that's my concern.

Comment: I would guess you could use a manager for those factory component. It is kinda slower and cumbersome but you would have a class that handles all the events and redirect them. This way you can watch who does what.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I cannot follow your idea, If a gameobject has a MeshRenderer, I think I can only query the renderer's state (enabled/disabled/added/removed) via Update(), the events happened on renderer are not be throw out, and I have no way to change the MeshRenderer behaviours.

Comment: I think you're asking if EVERY "thing" in Unity (say meshRenderer)  happens to have hooks to enable and other events.  Unfortunately the answer is just "no".  And there's no built-in KVO layer like if you're an iOS developer.  The answer's just "no", you know?  Don't forget that Renderers etc will **never appear magically**.  In your code, **when you make or destroy one** just raise an event. End of story.  By "raise an event" I mean exactly as Faf. explains.  Now thats the end of the story!

Comment: The way I meant is that instead of affecting the renderer directly, you tell the manager to do so and the manager redirect the information to the renderer and also prints out or whatever you want to do with the event. So for instance you want to know who set the Renderer off. The caller sends RaiseRenderer(this, EventArgs), then the manager receives, the event args part would contain extra info about what to do and the first parameter is who triggered the event.